# Custom Range Input

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc

I need to make a vertical range input slider vertical and have labels in logarithmic locations. I havent found any prebuilt sliders that do this.I just need direction on whats the best way to accomplish this. I have tried to overlay an image with the ticks but that didint seem to work very well either, any suggestions would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: di you try to rotate the classical range input by css? wrap it with some container to put labels on exact locations by absolute positioning

Comment: yes but that causes other problems I need a combination of custom labels and it being vertical.

Comment: see the edit in previous comment. to make it vertical, you need to rotate it. to labels positions you need absolute positioning. if the rotation causes the positioning problems, rotate only range input and the labels wraper leave unrotated

Comment: I'm really new to front end can you give any sample code I would be happy to upvote it.Also if the slider resizes similar to how materialize resizes will this cause problems for the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start from this fiddle. it is based on previous comments. Just create a container for whole component. Then rotate the range input to 90 degrees and correct the position by margins. Then create container for labels, where you will place all the labels with position defined by your needs

```css
#all { position: relative; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
#all input {
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: -30%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#all .labels {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  height: 180px;
  
}
#label1 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
#label2 { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; }
#label3 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
  <div class="labels">
    <span id="label1">0</span>
    <span id="label2">50</span>
    <span id="label3">100</span>
  </div>
</div>
```